# How to take rows from Oracle separated by comma

Tags: sql, oracle

This is what I'm getting

```
parent   MenuName Name     menu2    type      menuId   menu2Id
--------------------------------------------------------------
26  General Currency    Add 3   27  29
26  General Currency    Delete  3   27  31
26  General Currency    Update  3   27  30
26  General Currency    View    3   27  28
26  General Country Add 3   32  34
26  General Country Delete  3   32  36
26  General Country Update  3   32  35
```

I want to get like this

```
MenuId   MenuName   Name       Privilege
------------------------------------------------
27       General    Currency   Add,Delete,Update,View
32       General    Country    Add,Delete,Update
```

Please help with this

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You did not state your version, so I assume the current version (11.2):

```
select menuid, menuname, name, listagg(privilege, ',')
from menu
group by menuid, menuname, name
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `listagg` function for the same like follow -

```
select MenuId,
       MenuName,
       Name, 
       listagg(menu2,',') within group (order by 1) Privilege
from table_name
group by MenuId,MenuName,Name
```

[for reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using oracle 11gR2 then there are other ways - read [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)

And the XMLAGG way:

```
select menuid, menuname, name, trim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, privilege || ','))
              .extract('//text()')) Privilege
from table_name
group by MenuId,MenuName,Name
```